# Render face of cube map to a quad

Tags: opengl, 3d, texture-mapping

I have a cube map texture in OpenGL, and I'd like to render one face of the cube to a single quad. What texture coordinates should I use? To be concrete, what coordinates should I pick to render the "GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X" face? Or if I shouldn't explicitly define coordinates, how should I use texture coordinate generation in this instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The texture coordinates you want are (1, +/-1, +/-1)

Comment: Thanks, this was a good sanity check for me because I wasn't sure if my cube map was messed up or my rendering was... looks like the former, unfortunately.

Comment: How exactly is this done? Using a vec3 for texture co-ordinates in the shader?