# OpenGL - Render face of cube map to a quad

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk

I need to render a particular face of a cube map to a quad for debugging purposes.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565093/render-face-of-cube-map-to-a-quad) similar question I gather you use three dimensional texture co-ordinates, but I'll need a little information to get over this hurdle. All I'm getting is black at the moment, sometimes a different colour entirely.

Until now, I've drawn 2D quads with the following.

```
GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, textureID);

GL.BindVertexArray(VAO);
GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, vertices.Length);
```

Do I need to make an adjustment here? What is the general approach for doing this?

Comment: So, what texture coordinates are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few changes needed, which are all quite simple.

#### Texture target

Where you currently use `TextureTarget.Texture2D`, you will use `TextureTarget.TextureCubeMap` instead. For example, assuming that you already have a given cube map texture:

```
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMap, textureID);
```

#### Sampler type in shader code

In your fragment shader, you currently have a sampler variable defined, which will look something like this:

```
uniform sampler2D Tex;
```

You will modify this to:

```
uniform samplerCube Tex;
```

#### Texture coordinates

The biggest change is related to your texture coordinates. Texture coordinates used for a cube map will have 3 components, which can be interpreted as a direction vector. Picture the cube corresponding to the cube map centered at the origin. The direction vector given by the texture coordinates then points at the texel that will be sampled.

One option is that you modify the texture coordinates in the vertex attributes produced by your client code. You can expand them to 3 components instead of previously 2, and choose the appropriate values to isolate the face you want to render.

Instead of doing that, it may be almost easier to calculate the new texture coordinates based on the existing texture coordinates you're already passing to the shader code for 2D textures. Where the current texture coordinates span a square with extent [0.0, 1.0] in both coordinate directions, you need to map that range to the face of the cube, where the cube is centered at the origin, and has extent [-1.0, 1.0] in each coordinate direction.

To accomplish this, you use -1.0 or 1.0 for the coordinate direction matching the face you want to isolate, and scale/shift the input texture coordinates from range [0.0, 1.0] to range [-1.0, 1.0] for the other two coordinate directions.

Say you had the following in your shader code for the 2D texture case:

```
uniform sampler2D Tex;
in vec2 TexCoord;
...
    vec4 val = texture(Tex, TexCoord);
```

Then, for the `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X` face, you use 1.0 for the x-coordinate of the cube texture coordinates, and scale/shift the remaining two coordinates:

```
uniform samplerCube Tex;
in vec2 TexCoord;
...
    vec2 mapCoord = 2.0 * TexCoord - 1.0;
    vec4 val = texture(Tex, vec3(1.0, mapCoord.xy));
```

Equivalent for the `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X` face:

```
    vec4 val = texture(Tex, vec3(-1.0, mapCoord.xy));
```

For the `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y` face:

```
    vec4 val = texture(Tex, vec3(mapCoord.x, 1.0, mapCoord.y));
```

For the `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y` face:

```
    vec4 val = texture(Tex, vec3(mapCoord.x, -1.0, mapCoord.y));
```

For the `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z` face:

```
    vec4 val = texture(Tex, vec3(mapCoord.xy, 1.0));
```

For the `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z` face:

```
    vec4 val = texture(Tex, vec3(mapCoord.xy, -1.0));
```

Note that the orientation of a cube map face is kind of ambiguous. If you have specific expectations on the orientation of the resulting output, you might have to permute/mirror some of the values in the code above.

Comment: Thank you Reto, it's people like you who make this website the perfect tool for advancing in difficult areas of programming, respekt.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Reto's answer above, I came up with the following (pseudo-)code to render a given face of a cubemap to a quad with the correct orientation.

Example quad builder (C):

```
typedef struct {
    vec3 position;
    vec2 uv;
} shader_quads_vertex;

typedef struct {
    shader_quads_vertex verts[6];
} vert_quad;

// ...

// Don't forget to set vertex attributes correctly
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
    sizeof(shader_quads_vertex), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
    sizeof(shader_quads_vertex), (void *)sizeof(vec3));

// ...

// v3 *----* v2
//    |    |
// v0 *----* v1
//
// v0, v1, v2, v0, v2, v3

vert_quad quad = { 0 };
quad.verts[0].position.x = x0;  // v0 (0,0)
quad.verts[0].position.y = y0;
quad.verts[0].uv.u = 0.0f;
quad.verts[0].uv.v = 0.0f;
quad.verts[1].position.x = x1;  // v1 (1,0)
quad.verts[1].position.y = y0;
quad.verts[1].uv.u = 1.0f;
quad.verts[1].uv.v = 0.0f;
quad.verts[2].position.x = x1;  // v2 (1,1)
quad.verts[2].position.y = y1;
quad.verts[2].uv.u = 1.0f;
quad.verts[2].uv.v = 1.0f;
quad.verts[3].position.x = x0;  // v0 (0,0)
quad.verts[3].position.y = y0;
quad.verts[3].uv.u = 0.0f;
quad.verts[3].uv.v = 0.0f;
quad.verts[4].position.x = x1;  // v2 (1,1)
quad.verts[4].position.y = y1;
quad.verts[4].uv.u = 1.0f;
quad.verts[4].uv.v = 1.0f;
quad.verts[5].position.x = x0;  // v3 (0,1)
quad.verts[5].position.y = y1;
quad.verts[5].uv.u = 0.0f;
quad.verts[5].uv.v = 1.0f;

// TODO: Bind shader, set uniforms, push quad into your vertex buffer
//glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...);
//glBufferData(...)

// TODO: Draw 1 face, or 6 faces, or whatever you like. E.g. draw 6 faces:
//for (int face = 0; face < 6; face++) {
//    TODO: Set "u_face" to face index via uniform via glUniform1i()
//    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
//}
```

Vertex shader (GLSL):

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 attr_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 attr_uv;

uniform int u_face;

out vs_out {
    vec3 uvw;
} vertex;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(attr_position, 1.0);

    vec2 uv_cube = attr_uv.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;

    switch (u_face) {
    case 0:
        vertex.uvw = vec3(1.0, uv_cube.y, uv_cube.x);
        break;
    case 1:
        vertex.uvw = vec3(-1.0, uv_cube.y, -uv_cube.x);
        break;
    case 2:
        vertex.uvw = vec3(uv_cube.x, 1.0, uv_cube.y);
        break;
    case 3:
        vertex.uvw = vec3(uv_cube.x, -1.0, -uv_cube.y);
        break;
    case 4:
        vertex.uvw = vec3(-uv_cube.x, uv_cube.y, 1.0);
        break;
    case 5:
        vertex.uvw = vec3(uv_cube.x, uv_cube.y, -1.0);
        break;
    };
}
```

Fragement shader (GLSL):

```
#version 330 core

in vs_out {
    vec3 uvw;
} vertex;

uniform samplerCube u_tex;

out vec4 final_color;

void main()
{
    vec4 tex_color = texture(u_tex, vertex.uvw);
    final_color = vec4(vec3(tex_color.r), 1.0);
}
```

**Note**: The above code makes the following assumptions about your coordinate system:

- Vertex positions/UVs of the quad are always CCW starting in the bottom left corner of the quad.
- Right-hand coordinates (+X to the right, +Y up, and +Z coming out of the screen toward the viewer)
- u_face is interpreted as an offset from GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X (0: +X, 1: -X, 2: +Y, 3: -Y, 4: +Z, 5: -Z)
- +Y is rendered as if staring down -Z (forward) then tilting head back 90 degrees to look straight up (i.e. the "up" vector is +Z for u_face = 2)
- -Y is rendered as if staring down -Z (forward) then tilting head down 90 degrees to look straight down (i.e. the "up" vector is -Z for u_face = 3)
- The up vector for the other 4 faces is +Y, per Assumption #2

I did test this code, but for brevity I've left out of a lot of the boilerplate GL code. Hopefully you found this helpful.